# VideoView Uri redirection

Tags: java, android, uri, android-videoview

I'm displaying video from an IP camera, with videoviews. I have an API which redirects my HTTP link to a RTSP link. When I was using the RTSP link, no problem, I could display the video.

But now that I tried to use the HTTP link (that works in Chrome or Safari), my application can't display the video. I think it comes from the `Uri.parse(url)`, because I don't parse the URL that comes after my HTTP link.

Do anyone has an idea about that problem?

Comment: what does your logcat show

Comment: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://...